Connect an NodeMCU to a soil moisture sensor
I am currently trying to connect a nodemcu to an soil moisture sensor. You can find the schemes of the controller below. I understand that the analog output AO on the sensor needs to be connected to A0 on the nodemcu, but i am struggling to understand how to connect power.
On most tutorials online, there are pins for ground and VCC on the sensor. On mine, there is plus and minus pole pins. My guess is that the negative pin is equivalent to ground and the positive pin to VCC. Is that correct? Sorry if this is a silly question, but i come from a software development background and urgently need to improve my knowledge of electrical engineering.



yes, 0=gnd and +=vcc.
